# Adding a class to an element in quirksmode

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I try to add a class to a td-element using javascript with the internet explorer 8 in quirks-mode. That seems to work, because I can see the added class when I view the source, but my css doens't affect it so nothing visually changes at all.
I simply add a html class to change the background-color but nothing happens.
It works when running in IEs normal mode, but that's not an option because I can't change the site and it's running in quirks-mode.

**EDIT:**

Here is a simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .style1 { background-color: #ff0000; }
    .style2 { background-color: #00ff00; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>goes on</td>
        <td>and on</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableElement = document.getElementById("table1");
    tableElement.setAttribute("class", "style1");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it doesn't work in quirks-mode (tested with IE 8) although the class is getting added (can be viewed with IE developer tools)

Comment: Are you using straight js or a library? And can you add the js and the resulting HTML?

Comment: I'm using straight js, take a look at my edit

Comment: HTML class. Not CSS class. CSS has *class selectors* which cause *rule-sets* to apply to *elements* with *HTML classes* or classes in a specific XML schema that the UA knows about.

Comment: I've changed that to be less confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer 7 and lower (and 8 when emulating 7) have a completely broken implementation of setAttribute (and getAttribute).

Effectively it works like this:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.setAttribute = function (property, value) {
    this[property] = value;
}
```

This breaks when the property name and attribute name are not the same (such as when the property name is a reserved word (like class) or used for something else (like style)).

Use `foo.className = 'bar'` instead of `foo.setAttribute('class','bar')`

Comment: I am having a similar issue, just that my class would be something like:
 `table.Show1 .cellType2, table.Show1 .cellType3{
       display:none;
  } `   
this fix doesn't work for making the cells draw themselves back again.